# How can I learn the best way to call in sick in my company?

Tags: sickness

Is it ok to send an email the morning of (or day before) and not show up before getting a response?

My manager usually responds later than when i am scheduled to be there.

How can I learn the best way to call in sick in my company?

Comment: why are you not ringing?

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/1989-12-18

Comment: I have always emailed or texted

Comment: I dont have his number

Comment: You must have the company's number - use the switchboard or the receptionist. Also what does your company's rule say do?

Comment: @atxgis do you wait for a response? Or work till you get one?

Comment: @Yelk11 No, but my bosses have always been reasonable and would not tell me to come in if I was claiming to be sick. As long as there is no meeting or anything important scheduled a normal boss will be fine with email.

Comment: Any company will have a guideline to follow. Most companies want to be notified right away so they can cover your shift if need be. It is always best to notify the company before your shift start time. Really it is up to your manager. Make sure you ask your manager how they would prefer you report your sick days. They will tell you what they expect and it is as simple as that.

Answer (score 5):

I think it really depends of the culture of the company.

Often, organisations have an email box that many managers have access to to see who will be absent from office on that day, with someone sending an email to everyone with the list of absentees for the day.

In some other companies, if you need to be replaced for the day for example, it would be better to call in sick and make sure that the person who can replace you knows that they have to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sick right now, I recommend sending an e-mail to your boss, telling them your are sick and will be off work today. Provide your phone number in the e-mail and say they can call you if they need to get hold of you urgently.

When you are back at work, if you are unsure, talk to your boss and ask them if you handled it ok and, if not, what they would like you to do next time you are sick. If your boss is not happy with the way you handled it, then they will probably just discuss it with you anyway about what to do next time.

Comment: Definitely ask your supervisor. My current boss wants an email, but my previous boss at this same company was fine with a text message. At my last job, it had to be a phone call.